# Mute in the app

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

There is a code that plays audio from the Internet via ExoPlayer 2. How to make when an incoming call sound is muted to 0, and when the call is over, back to the original?

```
public class Player extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String stream;
    private boolean isPlay;

    private ImageButton btnPLayPause;

    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter;
    TrackSelector trackSelector;
    SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        btnPLayPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPLayPause);

        stream = "http://site.ru/radio.mp3";

        bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory streamSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(streamSelectionFactory);

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, new DefaultLoadControl());
        simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(this);
        simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_view);
        simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(true);
        simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
        Uri streamUri = Uri.parse(stream);
        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "yourApplicationName"), bandwidthMeter);
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(streamUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
            player.prepare(mediaSource);

        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        isPlay = true;

        if (player.getPlayWhenReady() == true) {
            btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_stop);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        NotificationManager notifManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notifManager.cancelAll();
        super.onDestroy();
        player.release();
    }

    public void onPlayPause(View view) {
        if (isPlay == true) {
            if (player.getPlayWhenReady() == true) {
                player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                isPlay = false;
                btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
            }
        } else if (isPlay == false) {
            if (player.getPlayWhenReady() == false) {
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                isPlay = true;
                btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_stop);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It is desirable to give an example or a link to a similar example

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement PhoneStateListener, something like that :

```
class TeleListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                // CALL_STATE_IDLE;
                setVolumeOn();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                // CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK; call ends                    
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // CALL_STATE_RINGING
                silent();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

silent() and setVolumeOn() is up to you, basically you have to keep current volume level on silent() and silent the audio, then restore it on setVolumeOn()

This how you register(start listen):

```
private TeleListener teleListener;
private TelephonyManager telephonyMgr; 
public void start() {
    teleListener = new TeleListener();
    telephonyMgr.listen(teleListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

And unregister(stop listen):

```
public void stop() {
    telephonyMgr.listen(teleListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
}
```